# IONIC -3 calendar language issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im created my university  project for using  `IONIC -3` , I'm   installed this calendar

```
npm install ionic3-calendar
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-calendar
calendar is working but i had some issue for calendar display `unknown language` how to removed this language

look image

[image]

Comment: Where it shows `unknown language`?

Comment: sir look at attached image near by calendar year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open below file

```
\ionic-v3\example\SoApp\www\build\vendor.js
```

and search for `\u5E74` and `\u6708` and replace like below

```
\u5E74 = Year
\u6708 = Month
```

That will be work like you want.